# How are Postgres partitions counted for the table size limit?

Tags: postgresql, limits

Postgres has a [limit of 32T in a single table](https://www.postgresql.org/about/), but what if the table is partitioned - is that 32T per partition now?

Comment: Yes, a partition counts as (and is) a single table

Comment: So just to be clear, a table with two partitions would effectively be a maximum 64T table? This aligns with my understanding of the underlying mechanism (same as Oracle's) but I wondered if there was something I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So just to be clear, a table with two partitions would effectively be a maximum 64T table? This aligns with my understanding of the underlying mechanism (same as Oracle's) but I wondered if there was something I missed. – Gaius Jun 18 '16 at 17:08

Yes, that's true. Just to be clear. As @a_horse_with_no_name said partitions are implemented as different tables.

Though if you have more than 32T in a single table, even if partitioned, I would think something is funky.

Comment: Well, I work with Pb of data, so yeah, pretty funky ;-)

Comment: Fair enough. That's a lot of data.